# How to add multiple images + text, save it as a single object so that it can be viewed by the user from a list?

Tags: android, xml

Hello Stackoverflow!

I have an Android project I'm working on, and I've found myself stuck on one of the desired features.

The idea with this specific feature is that the user can load/take 2 images, write a description and then save it as a single object. This object will then be stored in a MySQL DB and will also be shown together with all the previously created objects in an expandable list or similare. The objects themselves dont haveto be clickable, just visible, and they don't haveto be editable after their creation.

-My question is this: How can i add multiple images + text, save it as a single object so that it can be viewed by the user from a list?

This might seem like a silly question for most of you, but I am (obviously) a beginner, and after spending days trying to look for a solution without knowing what I'm even looking for I've decided to ask here!

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps.

There are two solutions that come to my mind.

**1st one - generating new image**

If you are giving the user a list of all images to choose from you can easily take all those images he selected (If you are having trouble implement this, please ask) and move on to next activity or fragment where you will give the user option to enter a description. 
In that layout you can have one LinearLayout (inside a ScrollView to enable more images than a screen height) and dynamically add ImageViews that will represent those images selected before.

At the bottom you have EditText for description (but that is less important now).

Once user decides to save this selection you can create new Bitmap from the LinearLayout having all images inside it. 
Here is a code below

```
mLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinearLayout.getDrawingCache());
mLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

You can even put that into the bundle for further "transport"

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putByteArray(TAG, bytes);
```

If you have any questions or maybe need some more snippets feel free to ask.

**2nd solution - creating a Map or an Array for your final object**

You can have something like this

```
class MyObject{
    List<String> selectedImages;
    String description;
}
```

This list can be list of Bitmaps or maybe even list of Strings representing the urls of images user decided to choose. (I would go with urls)

I'm not sure how you present those images to the user so I might not be able to give you precise solution.

The second solution is more flexible and optimized. It gives you possibility to modify (even though you said it doesn't need to, but just in case) and it saves a hell of space on server (due to saving only strings not whole bitmaps that are mostly repeated in some cases).

Again, I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I think you might've helped me clear my crative block! I will do try to form a solution based on your 2nd suggestion. Thank you Nikola :)